# Add a background overlay effect on Google Maps element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, vue.js, google-maps

I needed to  add some background overlay effect to Google Maps element. However, after adding the overlay the map controls are not working, as the overlay is in top of map elements. Is there any way to achieve this **without affecting the map controls**.

```
<div id="maps"></div>
```

```
#maps {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
}

#maps::after {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f7f8fa 0%, rgba(247, 248, 250, 0) 18.73%),
    linear-gradient(180deg, #f7f8fa 0%, rgba(247, 248, 250, 0) 30.66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

script

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"), {
        center: val,
        zoom: 12,
        streetViewControl: false,      
      });
```

The effect will be similar to below image.[image]

I needed to achieve the same map effect without interfering map controls. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: If the overlay is only for visual purposes and isn’t supposed to be interactable, then you can just use `pointer-events: none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `pointer-events: none` , solved the issue.

```
#maps::after {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f7f8fa 0%, rgba(247, 248, 250, 0) 18.73%),
    linear-gradient(180deg, #f7f8fa 0%, rgba(247, 248, 250, 0) 30.66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Credits: @Terry

Comment: the full-stop/period after `none` is not necessary!

Comment: it was a typo, corrected it. @ProfessorAbronsius